# Remove My Tags from sidebar in my account page

Tags: tags

I want to remove My Tags link from sidebar in my account page without changing in base files.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: can you please give us screen shot..

Comment: you want to My tag link for left panel..

Comment: I want to remove My tags link from left sidebar.

Comment: i had give you step by step process.please follow it

Answer (score 2):

Create a small module to do it:

Step 1) Create file Prasan_Customerlinks.xml at app\etc\modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prasan_Customerlinks>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Prasan_Customerlinks>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2) Create Navigation.php at app\code\local\Prasan\Customerlinks\Block\Account\

```
<?php

class Prasan_Customerlinks_Block_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation {

    public function removeLinkByName($name){
        unset($this->_links[$name]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Step 3) Create file config.xml at app\code\local\Prasan\Customerlinks\etc\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Prasan_Customerlinks_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 4) Then in your local.xml file add following code.if local.xml file is not present create at app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>tags</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

P.S. For more information you can check my post on my blog http://pradeepsanku.com/2015/06/17/remove-customer-account-navigation-links-using-layout-xml-magento/